# How do I resolve Ipv6 related errors from NetworkManager

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, journalctl

I started using `nmcli` instead of just `iwd`. I usually have ipv6 disabled. It works just fine but I'd like to get rid of th warnings.

```
# sudo journctl -u NetworkManager

May 30 09:51:59 1337 NetworkManager[499]: <warn>  [1653918719.7647] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[4: fe80::c2b0:7b0b:4420:320a]: failure 13 (Permission denied)

May 30 09:53:29 1337 NetworkManager[499]: <warn>  [1653918809.8212] ipv6ll[06195b9399eef6b4,ifindex=4]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to eliminate errors by disabling IPV6 on the device as well:

```
$ nmcli device modify wlp0s20f3 ipv6.method "disabled"
```

Comment: This worked for me, on EL8

Answer (score 0):

I used nmtui and set the IPv6 setting to Ingore on the interface with warning and then restart the NetworkManager.service.